# Best way to modify html before binding to it in AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing an AngularJS app that gets a list of posts from a server, and then uses an ngRepeat and a custom post directive to output all the posts.

Part of the post object is a blob of html, which I currently add to the directive by first doing an $sce.trustAsHtml(blob), and then using the ng-bind-html directive and passing the trusted html blob to it. It works fine, but now I want to modify the html before adding it to the output. For instance, I want to find all link tags and add a target="_blank" to it. I also want to remove any content editable attributes from any element. etc.

What is the best way of doing this? I was thinking of just loading it up in a document fragment and then recursively iterating through all of the children doing what I need to do. But I assume there is a better AngularJS way to do this?

EDIT:

here is a codepen with an example of what I have:
http://codepen.io/niltz/pen/neqlC?editors=101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `filter` and pipe (`|`) your content through it. Something like:

`<p ng-bind="myblob | myCleanupFilter">`

Your `myCleanupFilter` would look something like this (*not tested*):

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('myCleanupFilter', function () {
  return function cleanup (content) {
    content.replace('......') // write your cleanup logic here...
  };
});
```

Comment: I hear filters can be slow, so I prefer to stay away from them if I can.

Comment: Indeed. Overusing filters is not a good idea. If you always have to do this sort of cleanup, I'd rather do it as soon as you fetch the data from the server, in the service (or ngResource factory)...

Comment: This is what I'd like to do actually. I currently have an non-angular app that uses jQuery, and I use a bunch of jQuery selectors to get and then edit the data before putting it into my Handlebars template. Now I am trying to convert it over to AngularJS and I know Angular has jQueryLite, but it doesn't seem to have all the selectors, and I was also wondering if there was a more angular way of doing this than using jQueryLite (or loading the full jQuery up to do it).

Comment: [Here (modified codepen)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fhagK). I added the cleanup code closer to your data source (as soon as you get it from $http)... Check the `.map` array function out. The cleanup code is very simplistic, though, it's there just for demonstration purposes. This way you clean it up only once.

Comment: And, by the way, you can actually code that cleanup method as an angular `.filter` and inject it in the service where you fetch the data. Filters are not only used in the views…

Comment: My original question was what is the best way to modify the html. This would be where you did your regex stuff. I don't want to use regex on html, especially when the html could be poorly written (I don't have control over it) so I would rather use some sort of html parser. Previously I was using jQuery, loading it up, doing selectors for the things I want to modify, and then modifying it. Angular provides jQLite, but it doesn't seem powerful enough to do what I want. I know I can load jQuery before Angular and then it will use jQuery, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: I also know I can load the html up in a document fragment/hidden div and just do standard DOM operations without using jQuery, but that seemed like to low level of an operation and perhaps Angular had a better way. Perhaps my only option is to use either full jQuery, or just write lower level DOM manipulation stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add attributes that are themselves directives, then the best place to add them is in the compile function in a custom directive.

If they are just plain old attributes, then there's nothing wrong with hooking into DOM ready in your run block, and adding your attributes with jquery.

```
var app = app.module('app',[]);
app.run(function ($rootScope){
       $(document).ready(function()
                $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                       $('a').attr('title','cool');
                 });
       })
});
```

If you want add the attributes after the compile phase but before the linking phase in the angular life cycle then a good place to do it is in the controller function for a directive that's placed on the body element.

```
  <body ng-controller="bodyCtrl">
  </body>

   app.controller('bodyCtrl', function($element){
           $('a', $element).attr('title','cool');
   });
```

During the compile phase angular will walk the DOM tree, matching elements to directives, and transforming the HTML along the way.  During the link phase, directives will typically set up watch handlers to update the view when the model changes.  By placing a directive on the body element, it ensures that all directives have been compiled, but the linking phase hasn't started yet.

Comment: I have edited my question to provide an example of what I want. I think you may have the answer...but if you could expand on that then that would be great...I think I am still missing something.